# Reading Spring profiles from a @controller

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I want to link the maven profiles to spring profiles. The project is build in a war file. The application is a Spring application, not a SpringBoot, deployed in a Weblogic Server.

I have this `pom.xml` file

```
<profile>
    <id>debug</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <spring.profiles.active>debug</spring.profiles.active>
    </properties>
</profile>
..
```

and in the application `@Controller`:

```
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  final List<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
```

but `activeProfiles` is `empty`.

I got the same result using

```
<activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.to.activate>local</spring.profiles.to.activate>
            </properties>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are merely defining `spring.profiles.active` property value with a Maven profile. The property is available for the Maven build e.g. for resource filtering.

The value still has to be passed to a JVM running Spring Boot, e.g. JUnit tests are usually run with Maven Surefire Plugin which forks the JVM and won't see the properties if you don't use `argLine` configuration:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=${spring.profiles.active}</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Above is usually true for any Maven plugin used to start Spring Boot application.

Comment: I've tried the proposed solution with the same result :-(

Comment: @carlesxuriguera How are you running the Spring Boot application? Please add a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The application is a Spring application, not a SpringBoot, deployed in a Weblogic Server.

Comment: @carlesxuriguera then why are you tagging your post `spring-boot`? If it's deployed as WAR you need to save the active profiles somewhere, either in WAR on in WebLogic. In your case Maven is just a build tool, it has nothing to do with running your Spring application.